# SVG incompleto apenas no Chrome

Tags: html, css, imagem, animação, svg

Estou fazendo animações com SVG, usando CSS. No Firefox funciona perfeitamente o efeito com stroke + fill gradient, no Edge ele apenas ignora o gradient e por fim no Chromefica tudo certinho, porém, ele não "fecha" 100% a linha do SVG. Fiz os testes nos browsers mais recentes.

[image: Logo SVG Correto]

[image: Logo SVG com Erro]

Segue o link no Codepen: https://codepen.io/KamilePimenta/pen/jXeJNP

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
}

#header {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

#header .logo {
  flex-basis: 100%;
}

#header .logo svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#header .logo svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  fill: transparent;
  stroke: #054168;
  stroke-width: 3px;
  stroke-dasharray: 2500;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  -webkit-transition: fill .3s ease;
  -moz-transition: fill .3s ease;
  -o-transition: fill .3s ease;
  transition: fill .3s ease;
  animation: dash 2s linear forwards, stroke .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}

#header .logo svg .tmw {
  animation: gradient .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}

#header .logo svg g {
  stroke-width: 2px;
  animation: stroke .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes gradient {
  0% {
    fill: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    fill: url(#logo-gradient) #054168;
  }
}

@keyframes stroke {
  0% {
    stroke: transparent;
  }
  100% {
    stroke: url(#logo-gradient);
  }
}

@keyframes dash {
  0% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
  }
  70% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
  100% {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
  <div class="logo">
    <svg class="line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" >

                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#054168">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#054168; #68b5ff; #054168" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>

                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#68b5ff">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#68b5ff; #054168; #68b5ff" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>

                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path class="tmw" d="M17.1 205.2h313.8v85.9c0 .3.1 5.5 3.6 7.4 1.4.8 3.1.8 3.8.8.9 0 2.9 0 4.6-1 3.3-2.1 3.2-6.9 3.1-7.2v-86h50.7v85.6c0 .3-.4 5 2.9 7.4 1.9 1.4 4.1 1.4 4.9 1.4.9 0 2.9 0 4.7-1.3 3.3-2.4 2.7-7.2 2.7-7.4v-85.6h50.9v86.9c-.1 6.2-1.4 15.6-8.1 22.3-8.5 8.5-21.3 8.3-26.4 8.2-24.5-.4-88.2.1-174.2 0v-85.8c0-.5-.2-3.8-2.9-5.9-1.9-1.4-4-1.4-4.8-1.4-.7 0-2.9 0-4.7 1.5-2.9 2.4-2.5 6.5-2.4 6.8 0 28.3.1 56.5.1 84.8h-48.8c0-28.5.1-56.9.1-85.4 0-.4.4-4.6-2.7-7.1-2-1.6-4.3-1.5-5.1-1.5-.8 0-3.1.1-5 1.7-2.9 2.4-2.6 6.3-2.5 6.7.1 28.5.3 57.1.4 85.6h-50.5c0-33.9 0-67.7-.1-101.6-8.3 0-16.6.1-24.9.1v101.6H48V221H17.1v-15.8z" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
            <g>
                <path class="tmw" d="M17.1 205.2h313.8v85.9c0 .3.1 5.5 3.6 7.4 1.4.8 3.1.8 3.8.8.9 0 2.9 0 4.6-1 3.3-2.1 3.2-6.9 3.1-7.2v-86h50.7v85.6c0 .3-.4 5 2.9 7.4 1.9 1.4 4.1 1.4 4.9 1.4.9 0 2.9 0 4.7-1.3 3.3-2.4 2.7-7.2 2.7-7.4v-85.6h50.9V292c0 3.4-.4 8.6-2.9 14.3-1.3 2.9-2.6 6.1-5.8 9-3.7 3.4-7.8 4.3-13.9 5.7-2.9.7-7 1.4-11.9 1.5H254.1v-85.8c0-.5-.2-3.8-2.9-5.9-1.9-1.4-4-1.4-4.8-1.4-.7 0-2.9 0-4.7 1.5-2.9 2.4-2.5 6.5-2.4 6.8 0 28.3.1 56.5.1 84.8h-48.8c0-28.5.1-56.9.1-85.4 0-.4.4-4.6-2.7-7.1-2-1.6-4.3-1.5-5.1-1.5-1 0-3.2.1-5 1.7-2.8 2.4-2.2 6.4-2.1 6.7v85.6h-50.5c0-33.9 0-67.7-.1-101.6-8.3 0-16.6.1-24.9.1v101.6H48V221H17.1v-15.8z" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                <circle class="st4" cx="489.9" cy="214.7" r="10.8"/>
                <path class="st4" d="M486.1 220.7v-11.3h5c1.6 0 2.9 1.2 3 2.5.1 1.5-1.3 3-3.1 2.9h-4.8 4c1.6 2 3.1 3.9 4.7 5.9"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
  </div>
</header>
```

Alguma ideia de como corrigir?

Comment: Sem código não da pra testar.... Coloca o SVG ai. E coloca o HTML/CSS também!

Comment: Perdão, segue o link: https://codepen.io/KamilePimenta/pen/jXeJNP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seu problema é com o seu `path`, ele está começando no lugar "errado"...

Não sei te dizer pq um browser renderizou de um jeito e o outro browser de outro. Mas vou te dar uma solução para arrumar isso. Ficou 100% no Chrome e no Firefox

O que te sugiro fazer é um ajuste fino de onde começa o seu `path`, repare que aqui eu tenho dois SVG iguais, porém o `stroke` começa alinhado direitinho no X/Y do vértice, já no segundo SVG eu "ajustei" para o `path` começar 30% "pra frente" do vértice...

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Código da imagem acima.

```css
path {
    stroke: green;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
svg {
    fill: bisque;
}
```

```html
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path d="M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
    <!-- Points -->
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="90" cy="10" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="90" r="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
<svg width="100" height="100" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <path class="dm" d="M30 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"/>
    <!-- Points -->
    <circle cx="10" cy="10" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="90" cy="90" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="90" cy="10" r="2" fill="red"/>
    <circle cx="10" cy="90" r="2" fill="red"/>
</svg>
```

***Vc pode ler mais aqui:*** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths

---

### Agora vamos ao seu código

Esse ajuste é referente ao seu `stroke-width`. Repare que vc tem dois paths um com `3px` de `stroke-width` e outro com `2px` `stroke-width` Logo vc precisa somar ao primeiro m `1.5px` e ao segundo `1px`

Veja a imagem para entender melhor. Aqui aumentei bastante a borda pra fica mais evidente. E coloquei uma borda de `1px` vermelha por cima pra ajudar a visualizar.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Visto o exemplo acima e te sugiro fazer uma ajuste fino de "Move to" para arruma onde o `path` inicia. O `path` é definido pelo `d` e o primeiro atributo `m` é o "move to" onde a linha se inicia. Basta ali vc mudar a coordenada de `m17.1` para `m17.25` e `m17.15` assim sua linha vai começar e terminar no lugar esperado.

**Veja o seu código código.**

```css
body {
    height: 100vh;
}

#header {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100%;
}
#header .logo {
    flex-basis: 100%;
}
#header .logo svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

#header .logo svg {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    fill: transparent;
    stroke: #054168;
    stroke-width: 3px;
    stroke-dasharray: 2500;
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    -webkit-transition: fill .3s ease;
    -moz-transition: fill .3s ease;
    -o-transition: fill .3s ease;
    transition: fill .3s ease;
    animation: dash 2s linear forwards, stroke .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}
#header .logo svg .tmw {
    animation: gradient .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}

#header .logo svg g {
    stroke-width: 2px;
    animation: stroke .5s linear 1.5s forwards;
}

@keyframes gradient {
    0% {
        fill: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        fill: url(#logo-gradient) #054168;
    }
}
@keyframes stroke {
    0% {
        stroke: transparent;
    }
    100% {
        stroke: url(#logo-gradient);
    }
}

@keyframes dash {
    0% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 2000;
    }
    70% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
    100% {
        stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    }
}
```

```html
<header id="header">
    <div class="logo">
        <svg class="line" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 512 512">
            <defs>
                <linearGradient id="logo-gradient" x1="50%" y1="0%" x2="50%" y2="100%" >

                    <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#054168">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#054168; #68b5ff; #054168" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>

                    <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#68b5ff">
                        <animate attributeName="stop-color" values="#68b5ff; #054168; #68b5ff" dur="3s" repeatCount="indefinite"></animate>
                    </stop>

                </linearGradient>
            </defs>
            <path class="tmw" d="M17.25 205.2h313.8v85.9c0 .3.1 5.5 3.6 7.4 1.4.8 3.1.8 3.8.8.9 0 2.9 0 4.6-1 3.3-2.1 3.2-6.9 3.1-7.2v-86h50.7v85.6c0 .3-.4 5 2.9 7.4 1.9 1.4 4.1 1.4 4.9 1.4.9 0 2.9 0 4.7-1.3 3.3-2.4 2.7-7.2 2.7-7.4v-85.6h50.9v86.9c-.1 6.2-1.4 15.6-8.1 22.3-8.5 8.5-21.3 8.3-26.4 8.2-24.5-.4-88.2.1-174.2 0v-85.8c0-.5-.2-3.8-2.9-5.9-1.9-1.4-4-1.4-4.8-1.4-.7 0-2.9 0-4.7 1.5-2.9 2.4-2.5 6.5-2.4 6.8 0 28.3.1 56.5.1 84.8h-48.8c0-28.5.1-56.9.1-85.4 0-.4.4-4.6-2.7-7.1-2-1.6-4.3-1.5-5.1-1.5-.8 0-3.1.1-5 1.7-2.9 2.4-2.6 6.3-2.5 6.7.1 28.5.3 57.1.4 85.6h-50.5c0-33.9 0-67.7-.1-101.6-8.3 0-16.6.1-24.9.1v101.6H48V221H17.1v-15.8z" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
            <g>
                <path class="tmw" d="M17.15 205.2h313.8v85.9c0 .3.1 5.5 3.6 7.4 1.4.8 3.1.8 3.8.8.9 0 2.9 0 4.6-1 3.3-2.1 3.2-6.9 3.1-7.2v-86h50.7v85.6c0 .3-.4 5 2.9 7.4 1.9 1.4 4.1 1.4 4.9 1.4.9 0 2.9 0 4.7-1.3 3.3-2.4 2.7-7.2 2.7-7.4v-85.6h50.9V292c0 3.4-.4 8.6-2.9 14.3-1.3 2.9-2.6 6.1-5.8 9-3.7 3.4-7.8 4.3-13.9 5.7-2.9.7-7 1.4-11.9 1.5H254.1v-85.8c0-.5-.2-3.8-2.9-5.9-1.9-1.4-4-1.4-4.8-1.4-.7 0-2.9 0-4.7 1.5-2.9 2.4-2.5 6.5-2.4 6.8 0 28.3.1 56.5.1 84.8h-48.8c0-28.5.1-56.9.1-85.4 0-.4.4-4.6-2.7-7.1-2-1.6-4.3-1.5-5.1-1.5-1 0-3.2.1-5 1.7-2.8 2.4-2.2 6.4-2.1 6.7v85.6h-50.5c0-33.9 0-67.7-.1-101.6-8.3 0-16.6.1-24.9.1v101.6H48V221H17.1v-15.8z" stroke-miterlimit="10"/>
                <circle class="st4" cx="489.9" cy="214.7" r="10.8"/>
                <path class="st4" d="M486.1 220.7v-11.3h5c1.6 0 2.9 1.2 3 2.5.1 1.5-1.3 3-3.1 2.9h-4.8 4c1.6 2 3.1 3.9 4.7 5.9"/>
            </g>
        </svg>
    </div>
</header>
```

Comment: Muito bom, resolveu meu problema! Mas este erro de renderização você acredita que ocorreu na criação deste SVG  (Illustrator) ou a partir da manipulação do CSS com o stroke-width?

Comment: . Acredito ser uma característica de renderização do motor dos navegadores webkit, no Safari eh provável que de o mesmo "problema" mas só testando para ver... Não posso te afirmar com certeza

Comment: Entendo, farei novos testes, por fim muito obrigada! :)